# Why is `&&` highlighted on Github

Tags: github

On Github, I realized that `&&`s are highlighted in [this file](https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/blob/master/DotNet/proxy.ashx) but not in the other languages such as Java, JavaScript etc in the same repo. Does anyone know what the highlight actually means?
Thanks
Allen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is an ASHX (WebHandler) file. The syntax highlighting on GitHub it language-specific:

What is ASHX:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/what-is-an-ashx-file-handler-or-web-handler/

Another example of GitHub syntax highlighting for ASHX:
https://github.com/JamesDunne/sql.ashx/blob/master/sql.ashx

Comment: Thanks @Karl for answer! Quick follow-up questions: why `&&` is highlighted in ASHX file? Does it have special meaning there? Thanks!

Comment: No, not beyond the concept of "AND". That's just the syntax highlighting in use there. I believe that it could be improved but just hasn't been given the needed attention.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with [GitHub Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist), which is not selecting the right grammar for highlighting. The current grammar is expecting [this kind of syntax](https://github.com/caleon/juscribe.alpha/blob/f4454d5374917f4a3393a629f692334e6381ce25/public/javascripts/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/asp/basexml.asp) and is unable to highlight your file.

My guess is we'd need to select a new grammar just for `.ashx`. If you know a TextMate, Sublime Text, or Atom grammar capable of highlighting correctly `.ashx` files, please open an issue or pull request at [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist).